# Asking a company for permission to use website data for research

Tags: research-process, data, legal-issues

I'm a researcher, and I want to scrape a website (specifically, TripAdvisor) to collect data in order to use it for a research project. However, in reading the website's [terms & conditions](https://www.tripadvisor.com/pages/terms.html), I found that the company prohibits the user from:

> ...copy any content or information of this Website using any robot,
>   spider, scraper or other automated means or any manual process for any
>   purpose without our express written permission.
>
> -- Prohibited activities, bullet (ii)

As such, I want to contact the company to ask for permission. I've had a difficult time finding any information on how to contact the company in order to ask for permission to use data. That said, my question is, **when making these sorts of requests to companies, what is the best way to ensure that I am contacting the right department/person?**

Comment: Did you start with they're contact information? https://www.tripadvisor.com/PressCenter-c6-About_Us.html

Comment: I foud only their physical mail adress. I need their e-mail.

Comment: Their phone number is below their mailing address. Call them and ask who you should speak to. I have luck starting the conservation with "I have a weird question."

Comment: Okay. I will leave this option as last alternative. Thank you

Comment: This is both too localized and not on topic. At best, you could edit to say "how to approach online aggregators to use their data for research", but I suspect that question would only have answers that don't help you ("find the email and email them"). FYI tripadvisor has a whole help center website where your efforts are probably better spent.

Comment: I have attempted to make the question more general, but it may need some additional tweaking (or it may not be a good fit for this site).

Comment: Ok. thanks all for your help. Very interesting.

Comment: You might also try to use LinkedIn a bit. If you can at least figure out the name of the department that sounds realistic for this type of request, you might have a better shot.

Comment: I always thought that the use of data could be beneficial for both parties.
By using Tripadvisor as benchmark Dataset, I think that the company will gain more visibilty in the field of scientists as a reference in benchmark dataset. And concerning the "Sounds realistic", I would say that I come here just to find help to get email, and not to covaince anyone to help me ;)

Comment: @Superbest - I've made a few edits to make the question more general. I think there's a good question to be asked here that's probably relevant to quite a few researching hoping to get data off public websites with similarly restrictive TOS.

Comment: @MOHBOB: "I foud only their physical mail adress. I need their e-mail." - well ... why? Why not simply send a letter (yes, on paper)? Deleting an e-mail is still a little bit easier to do than "erasing" a physical letter.

Comment: And, just for the sake of completeness, [here is a forum thread on tripadvisor.com](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i12105-k9469396-Asking_permission_to_use_Tripadvisor_data_for_research-TripAdvisor_Support.html) where another researcher wanted to get some data access in April 2016.

Comment: Thank you for your help @O.R.Mapper.
I live in a country where a letter to USA risk to take months to arrive. I wish if I could send simply a letter :)

Comment: @MOHBOB: Maybe that only applies to "normal" letters and there are priority services that can reduce that time to one or two weeks? Also, aren't there any web-based virtual-to-physical mail services that would let you upload a file online and then print it and send it physically from within the U.S.?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:Thank you for your idea. Indeed it could be a solution. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, recognize that they probably placed that ToS there for some or all of the following reasons:

1. They want a legal basis for suing someone who tries to steal stuff from their site.
2. They want a legal basis for suing some idiot programmer who brings down their site because of a poorly programmed bot he wrote "for a project".
3. Their lawyer told them to put these ToS up because he saw them on some other large site and thought they looked good there.
4. ...?

You likely fall in the second category (and maybe the fourth, I don't know what other things they're protecting themselves from). To that extent, you have to convince them that you aren't an idiot who will run amok on their servers. If you're aligned with a well-known university then maybe you'll have more luck, but even then it'll be a stretch... this is a for-profit company, not a research institution. Even if you can convince them that you're not a total idiot, they still have very little reason to want to grant you this permission. Your pet project will gain them nothing, and may in fact demonstrate something bad about their site that they don't want public. The "I'll share my findings" argument really doesn't go very far... companies have their own interests, governed by many things, including politics, agendas, egos, and what have you. Your powerpoint presentation that may be done in a year or two that will probably be too technical for a business VP to understand anyways won't give them any business value.

The point of all the preceding words is just to convince you that you have quite the uphill battle here.

All that said, I would just start calling every "contact us" number I can get my hands on. Definitely start with the numbers on the "Contact Us" page. Don't be afraid to send a written letter! For phone calls, I like the phrase Jack St Claire used in his comment: "I have a weird question."

Success is easy to determine. Check your mail... do you have a letter (written or electronic) from the TripAdvisor legal team permitting you to perform the research? If no, then you haven't succeeded yet. Keep trying! Perseverance will be key here.

Comment: "but even then it'll be a stretch" - while your counter-arguments may be true in principle, I still think that statement sounds overly pessimistic. Research projects getting some temporary access to a company's data are by far not a rare occurrence ... or maybe that is my impression, given that I am from a field that is more likely to simplify usage of a company's services than reveal any undesirable details. In any case, my impression is that the companies' primary concern is less that a "pet project will gain them nothing" (that is somewhat compensated for by the simple fact that they'll ...

Comment: ... get another little bit of publicity, (mostly) for free), but rather, that some of their data is not meant for public access (user data, paywalled data, ...), and that, once they have agreed to provide data, it can still be a bit of a struggle to *actually* get something moving.

Comment: That is exactly my opinion @O.R.Mapper.

Comment: @eykanal : I work on recommendation systems, and I see very often academic research projects using data from Tripadvisor.
For the argument "won't give them any business value.", it seems that Tripadvisor have the habit to give access to researchers, but request the findings as a counterparty.
I think that projects like recommender systems could be very beneficial for their type of service.

Comment: @MOHBOB - If TripAdvisor has a good reputation here, awesome! That's much to your advantage. From both my experience and that of my colleagues, most companies won't even bother to give you the time of day.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Having worked for now three of those companies, my experience is that (1) they are very conservative as to whom they share their data with, (2) they have a very dim view of academics, and (3) their impression is that any publicity you'll get them is just as likely to be bad as good. As such, they will be very unlikely to share data. Some companies will be different, of course, but that's my general experience.

Comment: @eykanal: Thank you for sharing your own experience with us. I think that a will use dataset from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/ . I think that is more suitable for an academic project, and it's free (request citation only).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 things.

1) contact other academic researchers who got this data previously (you mention in the comments this has happened) and ask how they did it. This is really your best bet and the only thing that has ever really worked for me.

2) Use LinkedIn to figure out who is likely to handle such a request. For TA it could be someone in their legal department or in their machine learning group, perhaps. You can at least get the sense here of what the departments are. I have used this method in the past to get responses to my requests, although they were "no".

Also I will note that I once had permission from a company to scrape data and then the company did not shut me down, my university did because it thought I was a "hacker from China". Then both legal departments got involved and took the data back. So try to get a dataset directly from the company, not permission to scrape.

Answer (score -1):

I finally find help on ResearchGate.com. One researcher provided me some email addresses that he founds on [this page](http://elliott.org/company-contacts/tripadvisor/) and suggested that I email a request to the CEO (Steve Kaufer) asking for permission. I've emailed him a request, and I'm waiting his response. Hope this can help anyone in future.

Comment: Two comments: (1) The email address you posted is not necessarily correct (e.g., I found another one [here](http://www.ceoemail.com/s.php?id=ceo-75221)... I suspect they're just following common email address formats), and (2) emailing the CEO of a $9B company asking for permission to perform a research study is almost certainly a dead end. The likelihood of your getting a positive response is practically zero.

Comment: Not trying to discourage you, but definitely trying to *encourage* paths that are more likely to be productive.

Comment: This is really not the person you want. You want someone like the head of research or the head of analytics.